# Is there a way to write BlueprintJS MultiSelect overflow custom classname so that the position prop works along nicely?

Tags: css, reactjs, blueprintjs

So I have a `MultiSelect` component that has over 30 items. I wanted to prevent it overflowing the page, so I followed their `Popover` [sizing instructions](https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/popover.sizing), and set the max height to `300px` with overflow auto.

But now the `position` prop still thinks the `Popover` is still limited in height, and positions the the component as if it's still 1000px tall, covering up the search field. It seems that the positioning of this component is styled with inline styling, so I'm not sure if it's even possible to override this with custom class. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to expand the container height. I believe there's a modifier that prevents overflow, and it's on by default.